# Mute sound effects used by Windows Phone 8 speech recognition engine?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, speech-recognition

I have a Windows Phone 8 app that uses the SpeechRecognizerUI package to do speech recognition.  It works fine, but with every recognition session, the speech recognition engine plays a couple "bloop" style sound effects.  I'd like to get rid of them, but I don't see anything in the *Settings* property that lets me turn those off.  Does anyone know how to do this?

Note I already have  the *Settings* properties *ReadOutEnabled* and *ShowConfirmation* set to *FALSE*.

Answer (score 2):

The sound effects are part of the SpeechRecognizerUI, if you don't want to have them you can use SpeechRecognizer instead and build your own UI.

Comment: Ok thanks, that's what I needed.  Looking for a good SpeechRecognizer sample now.

Comment: Would you happen to know how to capture a speech recognition session in progress (SpeechRecognizer)?